# How to create config map and secrets using golang kubernetes API

Tags: go, kubernetes

How to create config map and secrets using Go lang Kubernetes API

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have your [Kubernetes client](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) configured with your Kubernetes cluster and then create ConfigMap/Secret struct and call Kubernetes API.

Here is a code example you can use:

```golang
cm := corev1.ConfigMap{
  TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{
    Kind:       "ConfigMap",
    APIVersion: "v1",
  },
  ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
    Name:      "my-config-map",
    Namespace: "my-namespace",
  },
  Data: <config-map-data>,
}

clientset.CoreV1().ConfigMaps("my-namespace").Create(&cm)
```

Here you can find the doc for:

- [ConfigMap](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api@v0.23.0/core/v1#ConfigMap)
- [Secret](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api@v0.23.0/core/v1#Secret)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please correct me if i am wrong. I think we need to pass namespace name in ConfigMaps("my-config-map") instead of configmap name.
clientset.CoreV1().ConfigMaps("my-namespace").Create(&cm)

Comment: You're totally right! Updated my answer.